# Where to Change IP on E71

Tags: remote-access, nokia-e-series

I'm trying to set up my nokia to navigate on my intranet, but I need it to have a static IP, anybody know where can I see this configuration and change it? I just can watch the access points but I don't see anything regarding IP's. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dannytalk blog](http://www.dannytalk.com/2009/03/15/nokia-e71-wlan-wifi-connection-problem/) has your answer:

> If you use a static IP address
>   (default auto), go to Menu, Tools,
>   Settings, Connection, Access Points.
>   Then edit your network, and under
>   Options, go to Advanced Settings. Go
>   to IPv4 settings and go to Phone IP
>   address. Put in your static IP
>   address. You can also configure proxy
>   servers, IPv6 and DNS in the Advanced
>   Settings too.